# how to group news or post by year and month in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

i want to group posts or news by year and month how i can do such thing

this format for example

> 2019 apr [post 1, post 2] may [post 1, post 2]
>
> 2018 apr [post 1, post 2] may [post 1, post 2]

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Are these posts stored in a database? If so, what database are you using and what field type are you using for the dates? Are you able to show any code you've tried so far?

Comment: yes posts stored in mysql database and date column is posts_date(DATETIME), the only thing i managed to do so far is either group by year or month not both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of laravel eloquent and Carbon

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$news = New::select('id', 'title', 'created_at')
->get()
->groupBy(function($date) {
    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y');
});
```

Comment: then will group them by year only and i need year and inside year month

Answer (score 0):

By default we can make group by only with primary keys. if you want to add group by with other attributes you have to enable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` sql mode by adding the below code on `config/database.php`

```
'mysql' => [
    .....
    'modes' => [
        'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
    ],
```

recommended modes:

```
'STRICT_ALL_TABLES',
'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
'NO_ZERO_DATE',
'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
```

once you enabled the mode then you can try the query here which returns the result group by year and month.

```
DB::table('posts')->groupBy([DB::raw("MONTH(posts_date)"), DB::raw("YEAR(posts_date)")])
->get();
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: it returned error : Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Comment: this will return 1 post from each year not all posts in each year.